# The assembly AjaxControlToolkit does not contain a Web resource that has the name 'jquery'

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a project in ASP.Net 4.5 Web Forms. When I run the project locally, it works fine. But when i deploy it I get this error:

> The assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.5.7.429, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' does not contain a Web resource that has the name 'jquery'. Make sure that the resource name is spelled correctly.

I have tried to remove "Microsoft.AspNet.ScriptManager.MSAjax 4.5.6", but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem today, when I point to localhost:port (or wherever is your case) the jquery error is shown. BUT when I point to localhost:port/Index.aspx (or your main page), the error doesn't show up. So I can imagine it may be due to the default page for the proyect not being set properly.